# SQL Server Partitioining on Date field

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

Need help - How to create partition in **`SQL server`** which will held **2011, 2012, 2013** data in separate file groups.

I'm struggling to understand between `RANGE RIGHT or RANGE LEFT....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please specify version of you sql server, and read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802.aspx

As for RANGE LEFT/RIGHT difference and decision to choose one for datetime column (I'm assuming datetime, but what exactly is the type in your case?), the command would look like this for `int` type:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION OrderDateRangePFN(int)
AS
RANGE [LEFT | RIGHT] FOR VALUES (100,200,300)
```

When you use `RANGE LEFT`, the first partition will contain values `<=100`. With `RANGE RIGHT` it'll be `<100`, and that's the difference really (please note that also NULLs will be handled differently).

In your example, if you wish to create partition function on `datetime` column, with `RANGE LEFT` your boundary values would have to be specified like this:

```
('20111231 23:59:59.997','20121231 23:59:59.997','20131231 23:59:59.997')
```

With `RANGE RIGHT` it'll be more elegant and plain:

```
('20111231','20121231','20131231')
```